# Efficient way of writing same process with different variable

Tags: python

I am writing a program; is there any efficient way of writing this? I want to improve my knowledge.

```
import random
import math

fighter_strength=random.randint(1,1000)
fighter_skill=random.randint(1,1000)
enemy_strength=random.randint(1,1000)
enemy_skill=random.randint(1,1000)




strength_difference=fighter_strength-enemy_strength
global skill_difference
skill_difference=fighter_skill-enemy_skill
global strength_modifier

if strength_difference > 0:
    strength_modifier=math.trunc((fighter_strength-enemy_strength)/12)
    print "You are stronger than the enemy by",strength_modifier

else:
    strength_modifier=math.trunc((enemy_strength-fighter_strength)/12)
    print "You are weaker than the enemy by",strength_modifier



if skill_difference > 0:
      skill_modifier=math.trunc((fighter_skill-enemy_skill)/5)
      print "You are more skilful than the enemy by",skill_modifier


else:
    skill_modifier=math.trunc((enemy_skill-fighter_skill)/5)
    print "You are less skilful than the enemy by",skill_modifier


print "you are done!"
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you clarify what the "variable" is that you want to be different every time? (You're probably looking for `sys.argv`, but maybe I'm guessing wrong).

Comment: That would be strength_modifier and skill_modifier as different process is done,although it not quite a variable

Comment: `global` does not do anything in this code.

Comment: This question would be a much better fit on Code Review SE

Comment: If the program does what you need but you want improve its code or time performance then you could post your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly reduce duplication, e.g. for strength:

```
strength_difference = fighter_strength - enemy_strength
strength_modifier = math.trunc(abs(strength_difference) / 12) # note abs
print "You are {0} than the enemy by {1}".format("weaker" if strength_difference < 0 else "stronger",
                                                 strength_modifier)
```

You could also look into classes and objects, for example as a very simple start:

```
def RandomFighter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.strength = random.randint(1, 1000)
        self.skill = random.randint(1, 1000)

player = RandomFighter()
enemy = RandomFighter()

strength_difference = player.strength - enemy.strength
...
```

Finally, using `global` variables is generally a sign of room for improvement...

Comment: To be fair, the `global` declarations, as he's using them, don't actually do anything, but your point is still well-taken ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you have two objects (figher and enemy) with attributes (strength, skill) you want to compare. So you need a Class with two compare methods:

```
import random

class Combatant:
    def __init__(self):
        self.strength = random.randint(1,1000)
        self.skill = random.randint(1,1000)

    """
     True if instance has more or equal strength
     False if challenger has more strength
    """
    def compare_strength(self, challenger):
        return self.strength >= challenger.strength

    """
     True if instance has more or equal skill
     False if challenger has more skill
    """
    def compare_skill(self, challenger):
        return self.skill >= challenger.skill


def main():
    left = Combatant()
    right = Combatant()
    print 'left st=', left.strength, ', sk=', left.skill
    print 'right st=', right.strength, ', sk=', right.skill

    print left.compare_strength(right)
    print left.compare_skill(right)


main()
```

Comment: THX A LOT EVERYONE for the great answer your onpening my mind to new code,Which I am really greatfull.

Comment: If you're happy with my answer please upvote it and mark it as an accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Complete this method, 2 or 3 lines. I am not going to do it for you, you will learn more if you do it your self. Then when done look at the math, there is some duplication in there. What functions can you define to help here. Just keep refactoring one step at a time, until it is done.

```
def report( difference , betterString, worseString, denominator):
    …
```

then

```
report(strength_difference, "stronger", "weaker", 12);
report(skill_difference, "more skilful", "less skilful", 5);
```

Comment: I need rank 15 uprove your answer  richard,can you write it fully because I don't really get what your saying I am only in year 10